# jdoc:include type="message" and style

Tags: joomla

I'm going to learn to make joomla templates so that I could manage my different projects with one template but I found `<jdoc:include type="message"  />`. What is it actually? What can I do with this? I also found this could be used only one time but in some templates it is found more than one time. So what is actual fact of `message`?

I also found this

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="anton" headerLevel="3" />`

What is `style="anton"` and `headerLevel="3"` ?

Comment: I think style="anton" is typed mistakenly.

Comment: I think style="xhtml" should be there instead of style="anton"

Answer (score 3):

From Joomla Docs:

**This element should only appear once in the `<body>` element of the Template to render system and error messages that occurred in the request.
CSS styles for system messages can be found in `templates\system\css\system.css`**

It basically shows messages such as the following:

[image]